# jQuery Animate text-color on hover

Tags: jquery, fonts, colors, hover, jquery-animate

Using the following code, trying to get the font color to animate on hover, similar to how I have the border-bottom-color animating. Changing the border-bottom-color works well but the font color just won't seem to change. A full example can be seen here:  http://www.buenolisto.com/alma. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am also already calling the jQuery UI in with: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.js

```
jQuery("li.social").hover(function() {
jQuery(this).find("img").stop(true, true).animate({
    'marginTop': "-=20px"
}, 'fast');
}, function() {
jQuery(this).find("img").stop(true, true).animate({
    'marginTop': "+=20px"
}, 'fast');
})
jQuery("li.reservas").hover(function() {
jQuery(this).find("img").stop(true, true).fadeOut({
    'marginTop': "-=30px"
}, 'slow');
}, function() {
jQuery(this).find("img").stop(true, true).fadeIn({
    'marginTop': "+=30px"
}, 'slow');
})
jQuery("ul.menu li").hover(function() {
jQuery(this).find("a").stop(true, true).animate({
    'borderBottomColor': '#2E9ECE',
    'color': '2E9ECE'
}, 'slow');
}, function() {
jQuery(this).find("a").stop(true, true).animate({
    'borderBottomColor': '#FFDF85',
    'color': 'FFDF85'
}, 'slow');
})​
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By looking at your code I can tell that you've forgotten **#** near css colors, so instead of this **`'color': '2E9ECE'`** use this **`'color': '#2E9ECE'`**. You may also want to work on your style, I have rewritten your last hover to something like this:

```
$('ul.menu li a').hover(
    function() {
        // do this on hover
        $(this).animate({
            'borderBottomColor': '#2E9ECE',
            'color': '#2E9ECE'
        }, 'slow');
    }, 
    function() {
        // do this on hover out
        $(this).animate({
            'borderBottomColor': '#FFDF85',
            'color': '#FEFEFE'
        }, 'slow');
    }
);
```

which, in my opinion, is more readable and shorter. Take a look at jQuery API [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) and [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

**UPDATE**: I've verified, this code works (tested with newest versions of FireFox and Chrome):

```
<html>                                                                  
<head>                                                                  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
    $(function() {
        $("a").hover(
            function() {
                $(this).animate({ color: "#00ff00" }, 'slow');
            },function() {
                $(this).animate({ color: "#ff0000" }, 'slow');
        });
    });
</script>                                                               
</head>                                                                 
<body>                                                                  
    <a href="#">aaa</a><br />
    <a href="#">bbb</a><br />
</body>                                                                 
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this code as follows and seem to be having some issue still. Colors are changing but not how I anitcipate them I would like the fon't color to animate to #2E9ECE on hover, and revert back to #FEFEFE when not hovered. I am a real novice at this so please bear with me :)       **jQuery('ul.menu li a').hover(function() { jQuery(this).stop(true, true).animate({'borderBottomColor': '#2E9ECE','color': '#2E9ECE'}, 'slow'); }, function() { jQuery(this).stop(true, true).animate({'borderBottomColor': '#FFDF85','color': '#FEFEFE'}, 'slow'); } );**

Comment: I have edited my post to match your colors, it's easy, just take a loop at the API.

Comment: The issue I was having was the first time I would hover over an element the animation would not kick in...but if I hovered over the element a second time the animation would execute. Then I had a problem with the current-menu-item not showing the correct color as well.

Comment: No did it did not work...the behavior was all wrong. The first time I would hover over an element after loading the page nothing would happen. Then hovering over the element a second time would produce the desired effect. As well, my current-menu-item CSS rule broke. I would still like to get this working though. Look at the API and it just went over my head. :(

Comment: @user1447958 I see, reread my updated answer, it should work.

Comment: Why would he need the color plugin since he already stated he's using jQuery UI?  See http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Comment: Yeah, it works in jQuery UI without additional plugins, I've edited my answer with working code.