# Fade in fade out on mouse over/out

Tags: jquery

i have "div1" and "div2", for example. and the 'div2' is hidden behind 'div2', and i want to fade in the div2 over the de div1 with a fade...
how can i do this?
i looked trought so many posts, and none of them gave me any result...

```
<div id="news1">
    <table width="100%" height="145" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="newsBox">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table width="230" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="89" align="center" valign="top" class="shadow"><img src="images/news_03.jpg" width="89" height="89" /></td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" class="espacoEsquerda">Duis felis magna, viverra ac dignissim at, mollis vitae felis.  Praesent eleifend dictum quam tempor lobortis.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="41" align="left" valign="bottom"><img src="images/news_10.jpg" width="35" height="35" /></td>
                        <td align="right" valign="bottom" class="readmore">read more »</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div id="news1Over">
    <table width="100%" height="145" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="newsBoxOver">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <table width="230" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="89" align="center" valign="top" class="shadow"><img src="images/news_03.jpg" width="89" height="89" /></td>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" class="espacoEsquerda">Duis felis magna, viverra ac dignissim at, mollis vitae felis.  Praesent eleifend dictum quam tempor lobortis.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height="41" align="left" valign="bottom"><img src="images/news_11.jpg" width="35" height="35" /></td>
                        <td align="right" valign="bottom" class="readmoreOver">read more »</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say "div1" and "div2" do you mean "news1" and "news1Over"? How exactly is one hidden behind the other? Please show your CSS. Those two divs seem to have pretty much identical content except for one of the images - what are you actually trying to achieve from the user's point of view? (If you just want the image to change on mouseover anywhere in the div there are better ways than duplicating the whole div...)

Comment: Sounds like you want either a [dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#default) or a [modal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/). There are plenty of options and the majority of them support animations.

Comment: i want to change the background color, and the font color, with a fade!

Comment: @Vitor Cabral In that case, you may want to look at the jQueryUI animation events. You can animate the text from one color to another, for example. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018483/jquery-animate-text-color-on-hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a jsFiddle for you to play with. I've used mouseevents to trigger the fades. don't know if this is what you want but it proves the concept.

Does it do what you need?

http://jsfiddle.net/2yERV/6/

```
$(function() {
    $('#wrap').mouseenter(function() {
        $('#news1Over').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
        $('#news1').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $('#news1Over').fadeIn('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
        $('#news1').fadeOut('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With proper CSS positioning, and some use of jQuery's [**.animation**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), this can be very easy. I've made a jsFiddle to show how easy using your HTML, however I made 2 slight changes. I wrapped the "div1" & "div2" in a "wrapper div", Gave each of the 3 "class names" and positioned them accordingly: wrapper is positioned `relative` so no inner element "floats out", div1 is normal position (default is static on div tags), and div2 is positioned absolute so that it lays over div 1. I then set the opacity of div 2 to 0 and set its z-index to be 0 as well, while leaving div1 as normal with a z-index of 1. The z-index is really only an issue if you want certain items clickable, otherwise, you can ignore it all together (will past a second jsFiddle without z-indexing). Finally, I use jQuery's [**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to determine where the mouse is over the wrapper element, and [**.stop**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) in combo with [**.animate**](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to "fade in/ fade out" the two inner divs.

See full example [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/P7WSW/)

And without `z-indexing` [***here***](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/P7WSW/16/)

> The slight change to HTML

```
<div id="news1wrapper" class="fade-wrapper">
    <div id="news1" class="fade-content">
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="news1Over" class="fade-cover">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

> The simple CSS

```
.fade-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
.fade-content {
    background: #FFF;
}
.fade-cover {
    background: #FFA;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

> The little bit 'o jQuery

```
$(".fade-wrapper").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".fade-content").stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1500);
    $(this).children(".fade-cover").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1500);
},
function(e) {
    $(this).children(".fade-cover").stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1500);
    $(this).children(".fade-content").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1500);
});
```

Comment: i've already have another id with z-index '1'... can i give another z-index?

Comment: yes, you can use whatever z-index you like, z-index really only affects overlapping elements. for instance, if two divs have a z-index of 1, but they are side by side, then their is no effect, however, if one div is on-top of the other and has a z-index of -1, then the div underneath will end up on top. understand? [Here is more in-depth about Z-Indexing](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)

Comment: i understand that... but, still have no effect... nothing happens!!

Comment: sorry for my stupidity, but this is my first year on html/css :s