# JQuery - change the h1 style with an animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

I'm new to jQuery.  I would like to have the look of `<h1>` fonts in my website change, but it should change slowly from white to black.

Here's an example:

http://www.worklifebalancecentre.org/

Here is the source code I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").animate({left:'200'}, "slow");
  $(h1).animate({color:'black'}, "slow");
});
```

but it does not work... :/

Comment: you can animate color if using a plugin which support it as jquery UI or jquery color

Comment: you can give your h1 a class/id and access it with $('#yourid').val('whatever') or $('.yourclass').val('whatever') then give them effects like $('#yourid').fadeIn() etc

Comment: BTW, on link you provide, i see only a fadeIn/fadeOut effect

Comment: found an answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018483/jquery-animate-text-color-on-hover it is on hover but you can change it to onload

Comment: Read up on CSS3 animations - they look better than Javascript animations and you don't need to add another framework, you can just change the css class.

Comment: ^^ that right there. css3 animations are just better for hovers like this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('button').click(function(){  
 $('h1').stop().animate({ color: 'red' }, 1000);
 });
});
```

click this fiddle link,http://jsfiddle.net/parsanamoni/pJefM/ .I hope this is correct suitable for your question.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery UI: http://jsfiddle.net/qZjHs/ (or jQuery + color Plugin)

```
$div.animate({ color: 'lime' }, 2000);
```

With CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/m47xL/1/

```
$div.addClass('lime');
```