# Hover animation fail

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am doing animation effect on buttons, but it does not work as should. It shoudl slowly show color on hover and slowly return to normal when mouse leave.

I took an example from [jQuery Animate text-color on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11018483/jquery-animate-text-color-on-hover)

Here is jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/eTymf/1/

```
$('.buttons').hover(
            function() {
                console.log(this);
                // do this on hover
                $(this).animate({
                    'borderBottomColor': '#2E9ECE',
                    'background-color': '#2E9ECE'
                }, 'slow');
            }, 
            function() {
                // do this on hover out
                $(this).animate({
                    'borderBottomColor': '#FFDF85',
                    'background-color': '#FEFEFE'
                }, 'slow');
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it by css as well.

Add below code to your css

```
.buttons{
    -webkit-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition:all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
```

Working example: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eTymf/2/)

jQuery SOlution: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eTymf/6/)

```
$('.buttons').mouseover(function() {
        // do this on hover
        $(this).animate({
            'background-color': '#000000',
            'color': '#2E9ECE'
        }, 'slow');
    })
.mouseleave(
    function() {
        // do this on hover
        $(this).animate({
            'background-color': '#fff',
            'color': '#333333'
        }, 'slow');
    });
```

Comment: It will not work in legacy browser(ie8 and below). So I have posted the jquery solution as well. For jQuery you have to add the jQuery UI as well.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is perfect, you just need to include the JQuery UI library...

```
JQuery UI library and CSS included.
```

And here is the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/nickg1/eTymf/4/

Answer (score 2):

if you really want to use jQuery:

background color animation is not a part of the .animate() method. you need something like the jQuery color animation plugin http://www.bitstorm.org/jquery/color-animation/ or jQuery UI like Nick G suggested.

also, you'll have to change `background-color` to `backgroundColor`

Comment: It should be noted that jQuery UI (what Rakesh's fiddle implements) uses https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/. You can use this by itself instead of requiring your users to download all of jQuery UI. Pure CSS is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.mouseenter()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [.mouseleave()](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead for the 2 different events.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.css` instead of `.hover`

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eTymf/5/)

**jQuery**

```
//menu cool animation
$('.buttons').hover(

function () {
    console.log(this);
    // do this on hover
    $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#2E9ECE'
    }, 'slow');
},

function () {
    // do this on hover out
    $(this).css({
            'background-color': '#FEFEFE'
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Normal Jquery animation properties only take in a number. For color strings to work,you need the jquery color plugin.

Include the [jquery Color](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin.